# hide + load + slideDown(), can't see the effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown

**Intro**,

I'm trying to write a new **function** to load content using the **slideDown**() effect from Jquery

This is the **function**, the content gets loaded properly, but i just don't see the Slide effect, i guess because  it might be done before the content its loaded, so:

```
function load_something(nombre,tipo){
            $("#router").prepend(loader_image);
            $("#router").load('/includes/router.php?nombre='+encodeURI(nombre)+'&tipo='+tipo,function(){
                $("#router").slideDown(600); return false;
            });
}
```

Tried also:

`$(div).hide().slideDown(time);`

getting same result

**Question**,

What i am doing wrong?

Thank you !

Comment: did you try $(div).slideDown(600, function(){ $(div).hide()});

Comment: i will and let you know, thanks for your note ;)

Comment: that way it hides and you will never see it again :(

Comment: sorry I couldnt understand the part where you said "you never see it again".Incase you wanna see it you need to do $(div).show();

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay.

I think you need to start off with router hidden in order to see the effect. If you have an external style sheet add:

```
#router {display: none;}
```

so that the content is hidden until you execute your function, triggering the slidedown effect.

Comment: Yes, I get that, but if #router isn't hidden when you update the existing content, you're not going to see anything with slidedown, I believe, because the content will already be visible; i.e., it has to be hidden to get the effect?